# Pass a Class to props in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am new to vue. I recently need to pass a class as a props to a component. As below:

```
<my-component v-for="(name, index) in　Names" :key="'name-' + index " :person="new Person(name)"></my-component>
```

Person as below:

```
class Person {
 constructor(name) {
   this.name = name
 }
}
```

Names are data from server.
The problem is when I update the name using `this.$props.person.name = 'Ken'`, it
does not change. I look into the `$props.person`, it missed `__ob__: Observer`.
Please help!!!

Comment: I think the. Jamb detection

Comment: Are you not getting a big warning about missing `:key` in your `v-for`?

Comment: I think the change detection would detect when you set a new person object into your vue bit it won't detect changes to properties of the object that you already passed in.

Comment: @Phil , no, i added :key for the v-for, but miss here

Comment: Please edit your question so it reflects reality.

Comment: @Phil updated, any idea about the behavior?

Comment: @mcgraphix I have tried to new Person in the data function and then pass it to the props, it works. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this helps:

1. Add persons:[] to your state
2. Use the persons array in your v-for
3. Push or splice new persons into the array using the names

`<my-component v-for="(person, index) in　persons" :key="'name-' + index " :person="person"></my-component>`

`this.names.forEach(name=>this.persons.push(new Person(name));`

Other stuff...

If your name is unique for person, use that in your key instead of index, or even better, add an id field to person to optimize inserts, deletions, etc.

You can also put your names in state too, and react to changes by adding persons in a watch function.

You might want to do a deep watch inside your component as well.  That code was not posted though.

Comment: Thanks, seems its the only solution, can you explain more why new Person in props is not working?

Comment: Did solution not work?  Seems like the stated approach is creating new person on every render.  This solution creates it once and stores the instance in a state array that can be reactive.